# Using DI in application written in Scala and Java - is it possible in "Scala way" - without additional framework?

Tags: spring, scala, dependency-injection

I have an application written partially in Java and Scala. In case of Scala code I want to use scala features to make dependency injection. In old Java code spring was used i.e. to inject services beans to wicket pages etc. In scala code I use selfless trait pattern to create services as described here:
http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/selfless_trait_pattern.html

Dependency injection in scala is done currently using "Configuration" object which wires everything together:

```
scala> trait Friendly {
     |   def greet() { println("hi there") }
     | }
defined trait Friendly

scala> object Friendly extends Friendly
defined module Friendly

scala> object ServiceConsumer {
     |  def myService: Friendly = myServiceInjected.getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("dependency not injected"))
     |  var myServiceInjected: Option[Friendly] = None
     | }
defined module ServiceConsumer

scala> class ServiceConsumer {
     |  def callService() {
     |    ServiceConsumer.myService.greet()
     |  }
     | }
defined class ServiceConsumer

scala> object Configuration { 
     |  def init() {
     |   ServiceConsumer.myServiceInjected = Some(Friendly)
     |  }
     | }
defined module Configuration

scala> Configuration.init

scala> val c = new ServiceConsumer
c: ServiceConsumer = ServiceConsumer@292e2fba

scala> c.callService()
hi there
```

But how to use "Friendly" service from Java class? Should I still use Spring? How to publish Friendly service written in Scala as a Spring bean?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the cake pattern is quite good for Scala DI. My favorite article about it is:

[Real-World Scala: Dependency Injection (DI) - Jonas Boner](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di.html)

Comment: But my question is not how to make dependency injection in scala (there are many options how to do that) but how to inject service written in scala into class written in java without using framework like Spring? Or - if this solution is not possible - how to publish scala service (scala object) as a spring bean?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I'll tell you about a practice that is working for me.

My Java code is plugged together using Google's DI framework called [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), the API for which I call from within my Scala code. By way of example, here's a module - that's a Guice configuration thing - that binds interfaces to their implementations. The API is a Java API, but I'm interacting with it from Scala code.

```
class UserSessionModule(storage: ActorRef) extends AbstractModule {
  protected def configure: Unit = {
    bind(classOf[ActorRef]).
      annotatedWith(Names.named("storage")).toInstance(storage)
    bind(classOf[UserSession]).toProvider(classOf[UserSessionProvider])
  }
}
```

I've found this to be a very hassle-free approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a factory method in Scala:

```
class MyService { def doSomething = ... }
object MyService {
  def create: MyService = ...
}
```

Then use it from Java as a static method:

```
import com.mycompany.myproject.MyService
MyService svc = MyService.create
svc.doSomething
```

Comment: Do you think this would actually work? I thought for calling Scala objects from Java you would need something like `MyService svc = MyService$.MODULE$.create`

Comment: @Landei In Scala 2.7 you did, static forwarders were broken back then.  But they work just fine nowadays!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring DI absolutely hassle-free with Scala.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/>

</beans>
```

And then I specify the components I want with:

```
@Service
class MyService
```

and then access it through:

```
class OtherClass {
    @Autowired
    var myService:MyService = _
}
```